# How to diff contents of re-wrapped lines?

Tags: git

I have some git-controlled text files that I just re-wrapped with a new line length. Before I commit, I want to check that the process didn't accidentally change anything meaningful.

`git diff` thinks almost all lines have changed, of course, making it useless. `git diff --word-diff` prints almost the whole file as (apparently?) context lines, so actual changes are still hard to find. `git diff --word-diff --unified=0` doesn't help.

Are there any better options?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-b` option of `git diff` to ignore whitespace changes:

> -b, --ignore-space-change
>
> ```
>        Ignore changes in amount of whitespace. This ignores whitespace at
>        line end, and considers all other sequences of one or more whitespace
>        characters to be equivalent.
> ```

so if `git diff -b` doesn`t return anything, you know only line endings or whitespaces were changed.